# Should all roles be allowed CRUD operation on the database?

Tags: plugin-development

Is there any limitation that any specific role out of (Admin/Subscriber/Editor/Contributor etc) can perform CRUD operations on database. In my WordPress website, all users are subscribers and they are able to perform CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

Users don't have direct access to the database, so in a sense your question doesn't make sense. Anything WordPress does is through, ultimately, the `$wpdb` object [using the credentials in `wp-config.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Database_Settings) (unless a plugin or theme creates a new `WPDB` object to access a different database).

So what a user can or cannot do is controlled by Wordpress Core code with possible modification by plugins and themes. If you want to know what a role can do, just take a look at [the Codex page for Users and Roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Roles). "Subscribers" can't really do that much:

> #### read
>
> - Since 2.0
> - Allows access to Administration
>     Panel options:
>
>   - Dashboard
>   - Users > Your Profile
> - *Used
>     nowhere in the core code except the menu.php*

But "Subscribers" must be able to do something, right? Just to be able to alter basic profile information-- email address, password, etc.-- which, really, is all a "Subscriber" can do.